# Retrieve number of posts

Tags: wordpress, navigation, themes

I use Wordpress and I use an Anima theme. Here is the menu code:

```
<nav id = "access" role = "navigation" aria-label = "<? php esc_attr_e ('Primary Menu', 'anima')?>" <? php cryout_schema_microdata ('menu'); ? >>
<? php cryout_access_hook ();?>
</nav>
```

This washes the site: https://simumods.com

How can I make sure that, in the American Truck Simulator subcategories, Euro Truck Simulator 2 shows in which category how many posts are there?

Comment: What is your question? related with nav or with post count?

Comment: I want the navigation to show in which category how many posts there are.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this isn't too difficult, first we will just check if the menu item is a taxonomy then get the count and display it!

```
function ggstyle_menu_item_count( $output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    // Check if the item is a Category or Custom Taxonomy
    if( $item->type == 'taxonomy' ) {
        $object = get_term($item->object_id, $item->object);

        // Check count, if more than 0 display count
        if($object->count > 0)
            $output .= "<span class='menu-item-count'>".$object->count."</span>";
    }    

    return $output;
}
add_action( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'ggstyle_menu_item_count', 10, 4 );
```

To get the Item count to output into the `<a>` of the menu item we will have to split up the $output and insert our content the put it back together.

```
function ggstyle_menu_item_count( $output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    // Check if the item is a Category or Custom Taxonomy
    if( $item->type == 'taxonomy' ) {
        $object = get_term($item->object_id, $item->object);

        // Check count, if more than 0 display count
        if($object->count > 0) {
            $output_new = '';
            $output_split = str_split($output, strpos($output, '</a>') );
            $output_new .= $output_split[0] . "<span class='menu-item-count'>".$object->count."</span>" . $output_split[1];
            $output = $output_new;
        }
    }    

    return $output;
}
add_action( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'ggstyle_menu_item_count', 10, 4 );
```

Duplicate post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229767/show-posts-count-for-categories-and-tags-in-wp-nav-menu

Comment: That way it doesn't show me correctly how many posts there are. For example, in ATS :: Bus, deleting a post from 21 dropped to 18. The other thing is, can I put these numbers in brackets. For example (18) this way they don't sit below as in the picture, and thus: ATS :: Bus (17) 

https://i.imgur.com/hqksKcd.png

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code

```
add_filter('the_title', 'wpse165333_the_title', 10, 2);
function wpse165333_the_title($title, $post_ID)
{
    if( 'nav_menu_item' == get_post_type($post_ID) )
    {
        if( 'taxonomy' == get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_type', true) && 'category' == get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_object', true) )
        {
            $category = get_category( get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true) );
            $title .= sprintf(' (%d)', $category->count);
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code for WP 5.5.1:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'prod_count_the_title', 10, 2);

function prod_count_the_title($title, $post_ID) {
  if( 'nav_menu_item' == get_post_type($post_ID) ) { 

    if( 'taxonomy' == get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_type', true) && 'product_cat' == get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_object', true) ) { 

      $cat_ID =  get_post_meta( $post_ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );  
      $term = get_term($cat_ID , 'product_cat' );   
      
      $title .= sprintf('<strong> %d </strong>', $term->count);

    }

  }
  return $title;
}
```